# How to create model in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, model-view-controller, model, nsfilemanager

I am a beginner in the Swift language. I have multiple arrays in one view controller from which I am loading data in the tableview.

My code is:

```
let filemanager = FileManager.default
var folderNameArray = [String]()
var completedExerciseArray = [String]()
var getCompletedExerciseNamesArray : [String] = []
var getCompletedDayArray = [String]()
var getCompletedDateArray = [String]()
var getCompletedTimeArray = [String]()

func getAllSavedDictionary() {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.allDomainsMask, true)
    for everyFileName in folderNameArray {
        if let documentPath = paths.first {
            let filePath = NSMutableString(string: documentPath).appendingPathComponent(everyFileName)
            let URL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
            if let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOf: URL){
                let savedDayDateArray = dictionary.value(forKey: "DayDate") as? [String]
                let savedDayTimeArray = dictionary.value(forKey: "DayTime") as? [String]
                let savedDayNumberArray = dictionary.value(forKey: "DayNumber") as? [String]
                let savedCompletedExerciseNamesArray = dictionary.value(forKey: "completedExerciseNames") as? [String]
                self.getCompletedExerciseNamesArray.append(contentsOf: savedCompletedExerciseNamesArray!)
                self.getCompletedDayArray.append(contentsOf: savedDayNumberArray!)
                self.getCompletedDateArray.append(contentsOf: savedDayDateArray!)
                self.getCompletedTimeArray.append(contentsOf: savedDayTimeArray!)
                historyTableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine but I want to know how I can make a model instead of arrays and load that model into the  tableview.
Here in `for everyFileName in folderNameArray`,
`folderNameArray` holds all the folders from `FileManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question.

A model is just a format for your data that represents it well.

An obvious structure for a single sectioned table view is an array of structs.

If you have a multi-sectioned table view, an array of arrays of structures works well, but ignore that unless you are dealing with a multi-section table view. (And ignore it entirely for now. No need to get too complicated at first.)

Just create a struct for your data:

```
struct CompletedWorkout: Codable {
    folderName: String
    exercise: String
    exerciseName: String
    day: String
    date: String
    time: String
}
```

Then an array of those structs:

```
var completedWorkouts = [CompletedWorkout]()
```

You'd then populate that array with CompletedWorkout items as needed.

Note that I may not have captured your intended data elements correctly. Also, the `String` type is probably not the best choice for many of your different properties (dates, for example, are probably best stored as type `Date`.)

### Edit:

To populate your model with values, you could hard code some sample data:

```
completedWorkouts.append( 
    CompletedWorkout(
        folderName: "folder",
        exercise: "Crunches", //Not sure what this is supposed to be
        exerciseName: "Crunches",
        day: "Tuesday",
        date: "08/15/2023",
        time: "12:47EDT"
    }
}

completedWorkouts.append( 
    CompletedWorkout(
        folderName: "folder 2",
        exercise: "Bench press", //Not sure what this is supposed to be
        exerciseName: "Bench press",
        day: "Wednesday",
        date: "08/16/2023",
        time: "13:04EDT"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me that, How can i append the model with data in my code?

Comment: In a real-world application, you would probably load your data from a file or database or fetch it from a server.

Comment: Yes here i am loading data from filemanager. Can you please tell me that How I can append data in the model? Like i am appending data in array in my code above.

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137171/uicollectionviewcells-are-hiding-while-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

No need to be confused with Codable. its just like you are mapping data into models

```
class UserImage: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let objectURL: String
    let isVideo: Bool
    let priorityCounter: Int
    let isDeleted: Bool
    let user: Int
    let videoAvailable : Bool
    let videoScreenshotUrl: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case objectURL = "object_url"
        case isVideo = "is_video"
        case priorityCounter = "priority_counter"
        case isDeleted = "is_deleted"
        case user
        case videoScreenshotUrl = "video_screenshot_url"
        case videoAvailable = "video_available"
    }
    
    init(id: Int, objectURL: String, isVideo: Bool, priorityCounter: Int, isDeleted: Bool, user: Int, videoScreenshotUrl: String, videoAvailable: Bool ) {
        self.id = id
        self.objectURL = objectURL
        self.isVideo = isVideo
        self.priorityCounter = priorityCounter
        self.isDeleted = isDeleted
        self.user = user
        self.videoScreenshotUrl = videoScreenshotUrl
        self.videoAvailable = videoAvailable
    }
}
```

you can do this by:

```
let dataObj = dataString.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataObj, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any> else {
        return
    }
    
    guard let user = jsonObject[APIKey.user] as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { return }
    
    guard let image = user[APIKey.image] as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { return }
    
    
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can i append the model?

Comment: in swift or objective?

Comment: Hi, here i'm not using api call for fetching the data. I'm using local database.

Comment: You would be better off to throw away your current file format and use the Codable protocol to serialize and deserialize your data. Google `Codable` There are tons of examples online.

Comment: please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77137171/uicollectionviewcells-are-hiding-while-scrolling